# android is it possible to writeprotect a plain/text file I have created using the StorageAccessFramework?

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

I'm working on a text editor and would like to be able to write protect a file.  Is this possible?  I can get its permissions from its URI using a cursor and (COLUMN_FLAGS and FLAG_SUPPORTS_WRITE) but I can't find a way to change its permissions.

I also figured out a way to get the physical file location on the SD card using the ParcelFileDescriptor's proc fd but file.setWriteable(false, true) doesn't work.

Thanks
Steve S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this possible?

No, sorry.

> I can get its permissions from its URI using a cursor and (COLUMN_FLAGS and FLAG_SUPPORTS_WRITE) but I can't find a way to change its permissions.

Those are not really "permissions". `FLAG_SUPPORTS_WRITE` simply means that the content is read-only. For example, [the "Media" provider declares everything it serves as read-only](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/08/06/ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT-may-not-be-read-write.html).

> I also figured out a way to get the physical file location on the SD card using the ParcelFileDescriptor's proc fd but file.setWriteable(false, true) doesn't work.

Correct, that's not supported.

Comment: @stevensmith: Android has never really supported marking files as read-only. Their philosophy generally is "if the user can see it, the user can do what the user wants with it". If you want to save content on the device and you do not want the user to modify it, put it somewhere that the user lacks access to (e.g., `getFilesDir()`). Then, consider a "save as", "export", "backup" or similar option to make a read-write copy of the content in a public place (e.g., using `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`) if and when the user asks.

Comment: In this case, I'm more concerned about accidentally stepping on a file I have created.